# Permanently disable tap to touch on XFCE-Awesome WM without using a Upstart script

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, xfce, synaptics, awesome

I'm using Awesome WM on a base Xubuntu.

The `Tap touchpad to click` checkbox in `xfce4-settings-manager` is ignored, presumably because I'm using Awesome WM.

Setting `synclient MaxTapTime=0` only works for the current session and doesn't survive reboot.

Creating an Upstart script just to run `synclient MaxTapTime=0` on boot sounds a bit silly.

How can I permanently disable tap-to-click, given the points above?

Answer (score 0):

I have added this in my rc.lua to manage synclient.

```
local awful     = require("awful")
-- {{{ Autostart applications
function run_once(cmd)
  findme = cmd
  firstspace = cmd:find(" ")
  if firstspace then
     findme = cmd:sub(0, firstspace-1)
  end
  awful.util.spawn_with_shell("pgrep -u $USER -x " .. findme .. " > /dev/null || (" .. cmd .. ")")
end

run_once("synclient MaxTapTime=0")
```

It requires awful to be installed.